# Lua - create a list of numbers to pass to a function

Tags: lua

I'd like to populate the parameters/values needed for this function, using `table.concat(mytable, ", ")` but no matter which way I try I’m not able to alter the string of numbers returned so it’s suitable for this function? Can anyone help ?

```
local function min_mean_max(...)
  local min = select(1, ...)
  local max = select(1, ...) 
  local mean = 0
  -- Iterate using the numbers, no need the index variable use `_` as a placeholder
  for _, number  in ipairs({...}) do
    -- Set a new minimum if necessary
    if min > number then min = number end
    -- Set a new maximum if necessary
    if max < number then max = number end
    -- Sum the numbers to find the average
    mean = mean + number
  end
  -- Divide the numbers by their quantity
  mean = mean / #{...}
  return min, mean, max
end
```

For reference this works..

```
local min, mean, max = min_mean_max(961, 335, 342, 453, 601, 767, 889, 936)
print("Minimum, mean and maximum numbers are", min, mean, max)
```

I either need a different way to convert a table/array `{961, 335, 342, 453, 601, 767, 889, 936}` or convert a string like this `“961, 335, 342, 453, 601, 767, 889, 936”` ?

Or perhaps there is another route ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's rewrite `min_mean_max`: `math.min` and `math.max` both accept a vararg (`...`); there's no need to convert the vararg to a table to iterate and count it.

```lua
local function min_mean_max(...)
    local n_args = select("#", ...)
    local sum = 0
    for i = 1, n_args do sum = sum + select(i, ...) end
    return math.min(...), sum / n_args, math.max(...)
end
```

(this differs subtly in that it expects `...` to consist of numbers, whereas the previous implementation would have accepted arbitrary objects properly overriding `+`, `/` and `<`/`>`)

If you want to pass a table/array to this function, simply convert it to a vararg using [`table.unpack`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack):

```lua
local min, mean, max = min_mean_max(table.unpack{961, 335, 342, 453, 601, 767, 889, 936})
print("Minimum, mean and maximum numbers are", min, mean, max)
```

(use `unpack` instead of `table.unpack` on Lua 5.1)

To convert a string into such a table or vararg, you would have to either split or simply extract numbers (more permissive). You don't *have to* manually `tonumber` the strings though - Lua's coercion will do that for you if you use the rewritten function. The second approach might look as follows:

```
local numbers = {}
for number in ("961, 335, 342, 453, 601, 767, 889, 936"):gmatch"[^,%s]+" do
    table.insert(numbers, tonumber(number)) -- for good measure: don't rely on coercion in min_mean_max
end
print(min_mean_max(numbers))
```

Comment: Thanks @LMD, I’ve not used table.unpack before, but if I try your first two code blocks above, it always returns `attempt to call field 'unpack' (a nil value)`? if this allows me to dump a  table/array into that function , then that’s what I need :-).  FYI - In my specific use case I’m pulling content from a bigger table into a smaller one via a loop and `table.insert(mytable,datasource[k]['watts'])` to understand the  min, max and mean.

Comment: @nodecentral Then you're probably using Lua 5.1 and need to use `unpack` instead of `table.unpack`.

Comment: That’s it, many thanks and I’m so sorry for not making my version of Lua clear at the start..